# Measuring ions through color change during electrolysis

Tags: aqueous-solution, electrolysis, color

I have very little experience in chemistry, you might consider me a physicist, and I am mostly not even sure where to find the information I need. I will start off by describing my problem, I have a nutrient solution (for plants) and I want to measure the different nutrients using electrolysis based on the color change. I have read that if a Copper anode is used the solution will turn bluish and if ammonia is present it will turn deep blue.

Now this is great and all, but I have 18 other elements/compounds I want to be able to measure and I have no idea how to figure out what materials to use for the anode/cathode to get color shifts which are dependent upon the different compounds found in the nutrient solution. How do you chemists go about finding out such things, do I simply have to test a bunch of it for myself or do you have a secret lair of wisdom somewhere?

I'm mostly asking for guidance in information seeking here, but if anyone is interested in the specific ions present in the solution they can be found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_nutrition

Comment: The problem is that nutrient solutions for plants may contain a lot of different ions. But their concentrations is rather low. I am afraid the usual color tests for detecting copper ions or any other metallic ions will not be sensitive enough to react with very low concentrations. Or if they do, they are difficult to find for ordinary people. For example, for detecting Manganese, you need formaldoxime. To detect lead in low concentration, you need diphenylthiocarbazone. To detect Aluminum, you need Alizarine Red S. To detect Zinc, you need diéthyldithiocarbamate. How and where to get them ?

Comment: @Maurice Would boiling off the water increase the concentration to measurable levels or do the ions escape too? I am willing to skip measuring some nutrients (especially micro nutrients) if it's very difficult to get chemicals needed to detect them.

Comment: @Maurice Basically, what levels are detectable? I'm guessing that percentages are detectable, but how about say 100 parts per million?

Comment: In general colorimetric methods are not super specific to a particular element. A second problem will be the low levels of some of the analytes. // Are you doing the plant growth hydroponically? Plants would extract some the nutrients from soil without the nutrients being in "solution."

Comment: Frankly if I wanted to measure a bunch of elements in a liquid sample I'd look at something like Inductively Coupled Plasma-Optical Emission Spectrometry.

Comment: @Beacon of Wierd. Formaldoxime reacts with Mn2+ up to 2 microgram or 40 ppm. Only Cu interferes. Diphenylthiocarbazone (or dithizone) detects Pb up to 0.05 ppm. Zn,Cu interfer, but may be eliminated by complex formation. Aluminum may be detected up to 0.2 ppm with Sodium Alizarinesulfonate (Alizarine Red S).These informations, ans many others may be found in books like Fundamentals of Analytical Chemistry, 7th ed, by Douglas A, Skoog, F. James Holler Donald M. West, Saunders College, 1991

Comment: @MaxW How small concentrations is that type of spectrometer able to measure? I'm also constrained to a budget, this is a hobby project so I won't be spending 1000's of dollars on it, but playing around with high voltage and plasma does raise my interest :)